# What is the PKCS#7 detached signature format?

Tags: standards, pkcs7

[This website](http://www.pkiglobe.org/pkcs7.html) claims that (emphasis added):

> In PKCS#7 SignedData, attached **and detached** formats are supported… In detached format, **data that is signed is not embedded inside the SignedData package** instead it is placed at some external location…

However, [RFC2315](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315.html) seems to define no such "detached" format.

- `SignedData` comprises:

  - `version` = `INTEGER 1`
  - `digestAlgorithms`: `SET OF DigestAlgorithmIdentifier`
  - `contentInfo`, comprising:

    - `contentType` = `data` (`OBJECT ID` “1.2.840.113549.1.7.1”)
    - `content`: `Data` = **the message that was signed**
  - `signerInfos`: `SET OF SignerInfo`, each comprising:

    - `version` = `INTEGER 1`
    - `issuerAndSerialNumber`
    - `digestAlgorithm`: `DigestAlgorithmIdentifier`
    - `encryptedDigest`: `EncryptedDigest` = the low-level signature

Neither `SignedData/contentInfo` nor `ContentInfo/content:data` are `OPTIONAL`; and the former may only be one of the six defined types: `data`, `signedData`, `envelopedData`, `signedAndEnvelopedData`, `digestedData`, and `encryptedData`; I see no `detachedData` or any similar options. (Choosing `digestedData` does not resolve it, as `ContentInfo/content:digestedData` is also non-optional.)

What belongs in the `contentInfo` field of a **detached** `SignedData` object?

Comment: \[Note that CMS has displaced/replaced/updated PKCS#7, so if you share this question be sure to check out [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652.html); it contains features such as replacing `issuerAndSerialNumber` with a `SignerIdentifier` that [may be optionally PKI-agnostic](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652.html#:~:text=When%20other%20certificate,non-X%2E509%20certificate%2E), so may be of interest to someone trying to do something that requires this question's answer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From section 7 of RFC 2315:

```
    3.   The optional omission of the content field makes
         it possible to construct "external signatures," for
         example, without modification to or replication of the
         content to which the signatures apply. In the case of
         external signatures, the content being signed would be
         omitted from the "inner" encapsulated ContentInfo value
         included in the signed-data content type.
```

So this "external signature" is a detached signature.

Comment: I see, so the `contentInfo` structure _itself_ isn't optional, but its `content` element _is_ optional... I don't know how I missed that!